# How to deploy spring-boot application war to Webspere?

Tags: spring-boot, websphere

I have spring-boot application with pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.0.4.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spring-boot dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--deploy on tomcat-->
        <!-- <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
             <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>-->
        <!-- swagger to provide list available rests-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--database connector-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--json to xml provider-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>myApp</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <!--<plugin>-->
                <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
                <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
                <!--<executions>-->
                    <!--<execution>-->
                        <!--<goals>-->
                            <!--<goal>repackage</goal>-->
                        <!--</goals>-->
                    <!--</execution>-->
                <!--</executions>-->
            <!--</plugin>-->
            <!--provide to split it and ut test-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

So, I need to build war and deploy it on websphere. But after deploy, there is error message:

> criptor count = 1048576
>   ************* End Display Current Environment ************* [9/20/18 18:35:17:893 MSK] 00000089 ecs           W
>   com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR
>   unable to open input stream for resource
>   META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class
>   in archive WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
>                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:147)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:124)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:120)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
>           at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
>
> [9/20/18 18:35:17:904 MSK] 00000089 ecs           W
>   com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR
>   unable to open input stream for resource
>   META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class
>   in archive WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
>                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:147)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:124)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:120)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.scanForHandlesTypesClasses(WebAppImpl.java:765)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:606)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5554)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5680)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1303)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
>           at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
>
> [9/20/18 18:35:17:911 MSK] 00000089 ecs           W
>   com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR
>   unable to open input stream for resource module-info.class in archive
>   WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
>                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:147)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:124)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:120)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJAR(ScannerContextImpl.java:275)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJARs(ScannerContextImpl.java:315)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1303)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
>           at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor89.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
>           at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
>           at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:664)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:91)
>           at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
>           at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
>           at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
>           at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
>
> [9/20/18 18:35:36:037 MSK] 00000089 webapp        I
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message -
>   [myApp#SBRiskDataSvcs.war]:.2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers
>   detected on classpath [9/20/18 18:35:36:906 MSK] 00000089
>   SpringApplica E org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
>   reportFailure Application run failed
>                                    java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding
>   method
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory.getDocumentFilter(Lorg/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Profile;)Lorg/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilter;"
>   during creation of class
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$330/0000000039C78270":
>   loader "java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoader@d1c57825" of class
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$330/0000000039C78270"
>   and loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@9d596fe4" of
>   class
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory"
>   have different types for the method signature
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:336)
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:215)
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:198)
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:185)
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:171)
>           at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
>           at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
>           at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>           at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:361)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
>           at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:620)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1413)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2273)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5554)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5680)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1303)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892) Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when
>   overriding method
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory.getDocumentFilter(Lorg/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Profile;)Lorg/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilter;"
>   during creation of class
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$330/0000000039C78270":
>   loader "java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoader@d1c57825" of class
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$330/0000000039C78270"
>   and loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@9d596fe4" of
>   class
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory"
>   have different types for the method signature
>           at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.spinInnerClass(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:339)
>           at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.buildCallSite(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:206)
>           at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:315)
>           at java.lang.invoke.DirectHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_L(DirectHandle.java:302)
>           at java.lang.invoke.AsTypeHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_X(AsTypeHandle.java:49)
>           at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.resolveInvokeDynamic(MethodHandle.java:841)
>           ... 120 more
>
> [9/20/18 18:35:36:921 MSK] 00000089 FfdcProvider  W
>   com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident
>   emitted on
>   /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/ffdc/server1_49377909_18.09.20_18.35.36.9168814475377962815599.txt
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup 131 [9/20/18 18:35:36:924 MSK]
>   00000089 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl
>   WebGroup SRVE0015E: Failure to initialize Web application Tomcat Host
>   Manager springboot.Application [9/20/18 18:35:36:929 MSK] 00000089
>   DeployedAppli W   WSVR0206E: Module, SBRiskDataSvcs.war, of
>   application, myApp.ear/deployments/myApp, failed to start [9/20/18
>   18:35:36:932 MSK] 00000089 ApplicationMg W   WSVR0101W: An error
>   occurred starting, myApp [9/20/18 18:35:36:932 MSK] 00000089
>   ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: myApp [9/20/18
>   18:35:36:942 MSK] 00000089 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0220I: Application
>   stopped: myApp [9/20/18 18:35:36:945 MSK] 00000089 CompositionUn E
>   WSVR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=myApp in BLA
>   WebSphere:blaname=myApp failed to start. [9/20/18 18:35:36:955 MSK]
>   00000089 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident
>   FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on
>   /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/ffdc/server1_49377909_18.09.20_18.35.36.9468746152542961403991.txt
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl 679 [9/20/18
>   18:35:36:970 MSK] 00000089 FfdcProvider  W
>   com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident
>   emitted on
>   /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/ffdc/server1_49377909_18.09.20_18.35.36.9567976105862242199088.txt
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke 679 [9/20/18
>   18:35:36:971 MSK] 00000089 MBeanHelper   E   Could not invoke an
>   operation on object:
>   WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=wasNode01,version=8.5.5.13,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=wasNode01Cell,spec=1.0
>   because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning:
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to
>   load webapp: Failed to load webapp: java.lang.LinkageError: loading
>   constraint violation when overriding method
>   &quot;org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory.getDocumentFilter&#40;Lorg/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Profile&#59;&#41;Lorg/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilter&#59;&quot;
>   during creation of class
>   &quot;org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$330/0000000039C78270&quot;:
>   loader
>   &quot;java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoader@d1c57825&quot;
>   of class
>   &quot;org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$330/0000000039C78270&quot;
>   and loader
>   &quot;com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@9d596fe4&quot;
>   of class
>   &quot;org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory&quot;
>   have different types for the method signature

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using WebSphere Liberty or Traditional WebSphere?  I assume Traditional.  It appears you configured the WAR to take over the root context `/` which is conflicting with the default application on WebSphere.  Try deploying to a different context root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, during your various edits, you removed original error message that was in first post:

```
SRVE0164E: Web Application MyApp_war#Tomcat Host Manager springboot.Application uses the context root /*, which is already in use by Web Application DefaultApplication#Default Web Application. Web Application Tomcat Host Manager springboot.Application will not be loaded.
```

which explains all:

You cannot have 2 apps mapped to the `/` context, so either change context for DefaultApplication that is installed, or for your application.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the Scanning of packages under META-INF folder , webshpere tries to match META-INF/* as a package to search for scanning packages as a normal packages which are under JARs. You need to configure Ignore Scan Packages for these packages under C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\properties\amm.filter.properties

like below for example :